# Struggling with retrieving object

Tags: javascript

Hi have some code here that will get / set an object to local storage.

The idea is that there will be an object called 'highscores' that contains the high score for each game.

I get an error saying *`this.appLocalData is undefined`*

I presume this happens because until the highscore object is created, it doesn't exists, so there is no way to add to it. I'm not sure on the best way to solve this issue.

Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/eL7ge/

```
var localStorageClass = {
    set: function (key, value) {
        if (!key || !value) {
            return;
        }

        if (typeof value === "object") {
            value = JSON.stringify(value);
        }
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    },
    get: function (key) {
        var value = localStorage.getItem(key);

        if (!value) {
            return;
        }
        if (value[0] === "{") {
            value = JSON.parse(value);
        }

        return value;
    }
};

var TestApp = {
    appLocalData: null,

    init: function () {
        this.appLocalData = localStorageClass.get('appData');
    },
    setHighScore: function (game, score) {
        this.appLocalData.set('highScores', game);
    },
    getHighScore: function (game) {
        this.appLocalData.get(game);
    }
};

TestApp.init();
TestApp.setHighScore('game1', 999);
alert(testApp.getHighScore('game1'));
```

Comment: you should initialize appLocalData

Comment: I see `localStorageClass.get('appData');`, but no `localStorageClass.set('appData', something);`

Comment: @saravanakumar: He/she does.

Comment: What's `testApp`? Note that JavaScript is *case-sensitive*.

Comment: Also, it looks like you're planning on calling `.get()` and `.set()` on the object returned from `appData` which appears to be parsed from JSON. JSON can't contain functions, so you won't be able to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? I've changed so that this.appLocalData = localStorageClass, corrected casing in alert call, and changed get and set highscore methods to use the same key for storing and retrieving values

```
var localStorageClass = {
    set: function (key, value) {
        if (!key || !value) {
            return;
        }

        if (typeof value === "object") {
            value = JSON.stringify(value);
        }

        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    },
    get: function (key) {
        var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
        if (!value) {
            return;
        }
        if (value[0] === "{") {
            value = JSON.parse(value);
        }

        return value;
    }
};

var TestApp = {
    appLocalData: null,

    init: function () {
        this.appLocalData = localStorageClass;
    },
    setHighScore: function (game, score) {
        var hs = this.appLocalData.get('highscore');

        if (hs === undefined) {
            hs = {};
        }

        hs[game] = score;
        this.appLocalData.set('highscore', hs);
    },
    getHighScore: function (game) {
        var hs = this.appLocalData.get('highscore');
        return hs[game];
    }
};

TestApp.init();
TestApp.setHighScore('game1', 999);
alert(TestApp.getHighScore('game1'));
```

**[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eL7ge/9/)**

Comment: Very close!. The game and score need to belong to an object 'highscores'

Comment: Much better! should I be able to access game1 score by using dot notation? Ie, hs.game?

Comment: game is a variable, so no, you cannot do that. You could, however, use hs.game1 to access it